# Execute programs from install location

Tags: c#, exe, executable

First I scan for every installed program on the system. From this I get the InstallLocation and DisplayName.
Now I would like to Execute the scanned programs from this Name or location.
Is there a way to do this or do I really need the name or location of the executable?

```
public static class InstalledPrograms 
{    
    const string registry_key = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";

    public static List<string> GetInstalledPrograms()
    {
        var result = new List<string>();
        var termsList = new List<string>();
        result.AddRange(GetInstalledProgramsFromRegistry(RegistryView.Registry32));
        result.AddRange(GetInstalledProgramsFromRegistry(RegistryView.Registry64));
        result = result.Distinct().ToList();
        result.Sort();
        foreach (var i in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);

        }
        return result;
    }

    private static IEnumerable<string> GetInstalledProgramsFromRegistry(RegistryView registryView)
    {
        var result = new List<string>();

        using (RegistryKey key = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, registryView).OpenSubKey(registry_key))
        {
            foreach (string subkey_name in key.GetSubKeyNames())
            {
                using (RegistryKey subkey = key.OpenSubKey(subkey_name))
                {
                    if (IsProgramVisible(subkey))
                    {
                        var ii = (string)subkey.GetValue("InstallLocation");
                        result.Add(ii);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    private static bool IsProgramVisible(RegistryKey subkey)
    {
        var name = (string)subkey.GetValue("DisplayName");
        var releaseType = (string)subkey.GetValue("ReleaseType");
        //var unistallString = (string)subkey.GetValue("UninstallString");
        var systemComponent = subkey.GetValue("SystemComponent");
        var parentName = (string)subkey.GetValue("ParentDisplayName");

        return
            !string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)
            && string.IsNullOrEmpty(releaseType)
            && string.IsNullOrEmpty(parentName)
            && (systemComponent == null);
    }
}
```

Comment: See `System.Diagnostics.Process` for information on how to start a program.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is **no** you can't find the application path using that part of the registry tree.  That information is install dependent.  You **can** find the uninstaller since that path is provided.  I seriously doubt that users of your program would be happy with you invoking an uninstall of every application/hot fix installed.

The only thing you can do is to scan those directories for `.exe` files.  If you only have one, then you might be OK.  Of course, if they were installed with an installer, there's a good chance an *uninstaller* lives in the same directory.

There's just no predictable way to simply launch every installed application.  Sometimes the installed objects are libraries and extensions to existing products.

Another thing to consider is that store apps have new rules surrounding how they are installed/uninstalled and even invoked.  Windows store apps don't have a ".exe" file you can simply invoke even if you could find it.

Comment: I don't want to just execute all the installed programs. I want to build a list of programs so users can execute their programs from this list. More like shortcuts.

I can scan the directories for .exe files. But those uninstaller in the same directory is indeed a problem. Any suggestions how to solve my problem or other ways to resolve this my problem?

Comment: Right, and store apps are another problem.  There's no way to tell which EXE is correct if there is more than one (and I ship software that has utility code in separate EXEs).